# Jest - mocking imported function from another file not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, mocking

I have been trying to mock a function which is imported in another file and used in a class. There are similar questions here and I went through a lot of them but still failed to get my tests working. Here is the structure of my code:

```
//util.js
export const stageHelper = (key) => {
    return STAGE_NAMES[key];
};

//main.js
import {stageHelper} from './util'
class Main {
    static config = {
        value: stageHelper('abc'),
    }
    
    static getValue() {
        return this.config.value;
    }
}

//main.spec.js
import * as util from './util';
import {Configuration} from '../configuration/configuration';
jest.mock('./util');

describe('Main', () => {
    const utilSpy = jest.spyOn(util, 'stageHelper').mockImplementation(() => 'testValue');
    //util.stageHelper = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'testValue'); // tried this too
    //utilSpy.mockReturnValue('ja'); // tried this too
    
    expect(Main.getValue()).toEqual('testValue'); // this test fails - the value is 'undefined'
});
```

I get `undefined` when calling `Main.getValue()` from my test. However, I expect this to return `testValue` since this is what I have mocked the return value as.

Could someone please help me get this right? This would be much appreciated!

Comment: (Did you try mocking `./util` before importing `Configuration`? I'm never sure if that matters or not.)

Comment: Yes that is what I have done

Answer (score 0):

You should spy `util.stageHelper()` method before import `main.js`. You need to use the `require()` method rather than `import`. `import` will import the original version of `util.js`. It will be too late to spy in your test case.

E.g.

`util.js`:

```js
const STAGE_NAMES = {
  a: '1',
};
export const stageHelper = (key) => {
  return STAGE_NAMES[key];
};
```

`main.js`:

```js
import { stageHelper } from './util';

export class Main {
  static config = {
    value: stageHelper('abc'),
  };

  static getValue() {
    return this.config.value;
  }
}
```

`main.spec.js`:

```js
import * as util from './util';

describe('Main', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const utilSpy = jest.spyOn(util, 'stageHelper').mockReturnValueOnce('testValue');
    const { Main } = require('./main');
    expect(utilSpy).toBeCalledWith('abc');
    expect(Main.getValue()).toEqual('testValue');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67115206/main.spec.js (12.867 s)
  Main
    ✓ should pass (44 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |    87.5 |      100 |      50 |   85.71 |                   
 main.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 util.js  |      75 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 5                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.066 s
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This approach does work if there are no tests before this block. However, with the other tests I have for the Main class, Main.getValue() is undefined. I also tried moving this describe block out on its own. Would you be knowing why this is the case?